# if I return a class in my function, where does it store?

Tags: c++, function, return, stack, nrvo

look at my code:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
> class MyClass{
> public:
>     char ch[50] = "abcd1234";
> };
> MyClass myFunction(){
>     MyClass myClass;
>     return myClass;
> }
> int main()
> {
>     cout<<myFunction().ch;
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

i can't understand where my return value is stored? is it stored in stack? in heap? and does it remain in memory until my program finished?

if it be stored in stack can i be sure that my class values never change?

please explain the mechanism of these return. and if returning structure is different to returning class?

Comment: The *one and only* difference between struct and class in C++ is the default access level (public for struct, private for class)

Comment: @Borgleader And also default inheritance. public for struct, private for class.

Comment: @NeilButterworth ITYM default access level to parent classes ;)

Comment: @Borgleader No, I don't mean that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyClass myClass;` is stored on the stack. It's destroyed immediately after `myFunction()` exits.

When you `return` it, a copy is made on the stack. This copy exists until the end of the enclosing expression: `cout << myFunction().ch;`

---

Note that if your compiler is smart enough, the second object shouldn't be created at all. Rather, the first object will live until the end of the enclosing expression. This is called *NRVO*, *named return value optimization*.

Also note that the standard doesn't define "stack". But any common implementation will use a stack in this case.

---

> if returning structure is different to returning class?

There are no structures in C++; keyword `struct` creates classes. The only difference between `class` and `struct` is the default member access, so the answer is "no".

Comment: i thought the stack memory given by function should release after returning.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the implementation to find a sensible place to store that value. While it's usually on the stack, the language definition does not impose any requirements on where it's actually stored. The returned value is a temporary object, and it gets destroyed at the end of the full statement where it is created; that is, it gets destroyed at the `;` at the end of the line that calls `myFunction()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an object in any function it's destroyed as soon as the function execution is finished just like in variables.
But when you return a object from a function firstly compiler creates a local instance of this object in heap called unnamed_temporary then destroyes the object you created. And copies the contents of unnamed_temporary on call. Then it destroyes this unnamed _temporary also.
Anything you create without the keyword new will be created in stack.
Yes,contets of your variable ch will not change unless you access that variable and change it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The instance returned by *myFunction* is temporary, it disappears when it stop to be useful, so it doesn't exist after after the `cout <<...`. Just add a destructor and you will see when it is called.

What do you mean about *can i be sure that my class values never change?* ? You get a *copy* of the instance.

*returning structure is different to returning class?* : a *struct* is like a *class* where all is public by default, this is the alone difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning a copy of an object. It will be stored in the stack in memory.
The returning obj. will exist until the scope of that function. After that, it will be destroyed. Then, your expression `cout<<function();` will also have the copy of that obj. which is returned by the function. IT will be completely destroyed after the running of this `cout<<function();` expression.